# FileStream read ending prematurely

Tags: c#, return, filestream

I have a function that strips a wav file from a video, then using FileStream I read from the wavefile. The problem is, the read function returns -1 (no more bytes to be read) prematurely. Its a 20 minute wav file, but only about 17.5 minutes are written.

In this function, I am mixing several wave files into a one large one. The problem is the filestream reader for the large wave file is ending too early. I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
public void combineWaveFileData(object status)
        {


        //ProgressWindow progressWindow = status as ProgressWindow;
        ExportProgressWindow exportProgressWindow = status as ExportProgressWindow;            
        string videoAudioFile = outfileName + ".temp";                       
        int descriptionStartSample = 0;
        int highestNumber = 0;
        int extraSamplesFromExtendedDescription = 0;
        const double VOLUME_VIDEO_FACTOR = 0.8;           //controls video volume levels; won't be const as volume control will be added later
        const double VOLUME_DESCRIPTION_FACTOR = 1.5;     //controls description volume levels
        double currentSample = 0;          //keeps track of the current sample in the video audio track

        byte[] videoAudioBuffer = new byte[4];//new byte[bitsPerSample / 8];
        int sample = 0;                  //holds raw audio data sample
        int videoReadStatus = 1;
        int descriptionEndSample = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
        FileStream tempStream;


        videoAudioStream = new FileStream(videoAudioFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        videoAudioStream.Seek(DATA_START_POS - 4, 0);
        videoAudioStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        totalRawSoundDataBits = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        //totalRawSoundDataBits = videoAudioStream.Length;

        videoAudioStream.Seek(24, 0);
        videoAudioStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);
        int videoSampleRate = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        sampleRateHz = videoSampleRate;


        outFileStream = new FileStream(outfileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        videoAudioStream.Seek(0, 0);
        writeAudioFileHeader(outFileStream, videoAudioStream);

       // videoAudioStream.Seek(0, 0); //reset video audio position to 0 (beginning)
        convertStatus = false;

        if (compatibilityIssue)
        {
            exportProgressWindow.Close();
            return;
        }

        //calculate total length of extended description files 
        foreach (Description description in descriptionList)
        {
            if (description.IsExtendedDescription)
            {
                tempStream = new FileStream(description.getFilename(), FileMode.Open);
                totalRawSoundDataBits += tempStream.Length - DATA_START_POS;

                try
                {
                    tempStream.Close();
                    tempStream.Dispose();
                    tempStream = null;
                }
                catch { }
            }


            WaveReader read = new WaveReader(File.OpenRead(description.getFilename()));
            IntPtr oldFormat = read.ReadFormat();
            WaveFormat waveformat = AudioCompressionManager.GetWaveFormat(oldFormat);
            int descriptionSampleRateHz = waveformat.nSamplesPerSec;
            read.Close();
            string resampledFilename = description.getFilename();


            if (descriptionSampleRateHz != sampleRateHz)
            {

                exportProgressWindow.SetText(".");
                resampledFilename = convertSampleRate(description.getFilename(), sampleRateHz);
                description.setFilename(resampledFilename);

            }

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < descriptionList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < descriptionList.Count; j++)
            {
                Description tempDescription;

                if (((Description)descriptionList[i]).getStart() < ((Description)descriptionList[j]).getStart())
                {
                    tempDescription = (Description)descriptionList[j];
                    descriptionList[j] = descriptionList[i];
                    descriptionList[i] = tempDescription;
                }
            }
        }


        int k = 0;

        while (videoReadStatus > 0)
        {
            try
            {

                    Description description;
                    description = (Description)descriptionList[k];

                    descriptionStartSample = (int)Math.Truncate(sampleRateHz * description.getStart());
                    descriptionEndSample = (int)Math.Truncate(sampleRateHz * description.getEnd());


                    if (videoAudioStream.Position / 4 > descriptionStartSample )
                    {
                        double currentTime = videoAudioStream.Position / 4 / sampleRateHz;

                        Console.WriteLine(currentTime+ " " + description.getStart() + " " + description.getEnd());
                        if (k < descriptionList.Count - 1)
                        {
                            k++;
                        }
                        double percentage = Convert.ToDouble(k) / Convert.ToDouble(descriptionList.Count) * 100.0;
                        try
                        {
                            exportProgressWindow.Increment(percentage);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        buffer = new byte[4];
                        tempStream = new FileStream(description.getFilename(), FileMode.Open);
                        try
                        {
                            tempStream.Seek(44, 0);  //to search for position 34; write: use writeSample() 
                            int tempReadStatus = 1;
                            while (tempReadStatus > 0 && videoReadStatus > 0)//(currentSample < descriptionEndSample)
                            {
                                //If description isn't an extended description then mix the description with the video audio
                                if (!description.IsExtendedDescription)
                                {
                                    videoReadStatus = videoAudioStream.Read(videoAudioBuffer, 0, 2);                                          
                                    tempReadStatus = tempStream.Read(buffer, 0, 2);
                                    if (videoReadStatus == 0)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(currentTime);
                                        int debug = 0;
                                    }
                                    if (tempReadStatus <= 0 || videoReadStatus <=0)
                                    {
                                        int deleteme = 0;
                                    }
                                    sample += (int)(((BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 0))* VOLUME_DESCRIPTION_FACTOR + (BitConverter.ToInt16(videoAudioBuffer, 0) * VOLUME_VIDEO_FACTOR)) / 2);
                                    writeSample(sample);                                        


                                    sample = 0;                                      
                                }
                                else
                                // If description is extended then only write the description samples     
                                {
                                    int tempStatus = 1;
                                    while (tempReadStatus > 0)
                                    {
                                        tempReadStatus = tempStream.Read(buffer, 0, 2);
                                        sample = (int)((BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 0)));// -((sample * (int)(BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 0))) / 65535); //Z = A+B-AB/65535 http://www.vttoth.com/CMS/index.php/technical-notes/68  //* VOLUME_DESCRIPTION_FACTOR);                                                                                                            
                                        writeSample(sample);
                                        sample = 0;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Debug 1: " + ex.Message);//MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            tempStream.Close();
                            tempStream.Dispose();
                            tempStream = null;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            videoReadStatus = videoAudioStream.Read(videoAudioBuffer, 0, 2);
                            sample += (int)((BitConverter.ToInt16(videoAudioBuffer, 0)) * VOLUME_VIDEO_FACTOR) ;

                            if (videoReadStatus == 0)
                            {
                                int debug = 0;
                            }

                            writeSample(sample);
                            sample = 0;

                            convertStatus = true;

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            int test = 0;
                        }
                    }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.GetBaseException().ToString());
            }

        }

            exportProgressWindow.SetText("\n\nLiveDescribe has successfully exported the file."); 

        try
        {
            closeStreams();
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


    }
```

Comment: You can't expect us to read all of this. Can you *considerably* shorten the code? This will help you get answers.

Comment: @usr:  _If_ the a/v API is involved then this is a reasonably compact question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I was under the impression that there is a problem with reading from a FileStream. Anyway, I cannot believe it takes 10 pages to create a repro.